# hashdeep comparison for modified code in two different folders

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to capture the file path info of modified code of two different folders(For example z-1 , z-2 folders (z-2 can be the patched version of z-1))

Desired Inputs and Output:

This is the below script worked upon with description
The below command captures the checksum values of all the files and saves in result.txt file

```
diff <(sort <(md5deep -r z-1)) <(sort <(md5deep -r z-2)) >> result.txt
```

It is used to seperate the two different folder files for using diff command to compare them

```
cat result.txt | grep "z-1">> z-1.txt
cat result.txt | grep "z-2" >> z-2.txt
```

Here comes my problem i want to diff the check sums of two diff files z-1.txt,z-2.txt and capture the corresponding file names(both from z-1 & z-2) with their relative paths.

```
cat z-1.txt | awk '{print $2}' >> z1_checksum.txt
cat z-2.txt | awk '{print $2}' >> z2_checksum.txt
```

The above 2 capturing only checksum values i want to capture the complete path of the files along with the checksum to find only the modified code file paths in  two different folders.

Output required: The diff should compare the checksum values that was captured previously (not the file->folder name or any path names  because in my case diff is comparing even my folder name of a file if it is different it is capturing as modified, but my main aim is related to file content) and display the complete path of file if it is modified.

Comment: Final step is not solving for me.For example i had 4 checksum values in column wise in one file `test1.txt` and another file `test2.txt` contains checksum + filepath.I want to compare `test1.txt` checksums with `test2.txt` checksums if a match is found in `test2.txt` files i want the complete path to be printed from `text2.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[i]=$1;next} ($1 in a) { print $2}' text1.txt text2.txt
```

refer [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) for more details